# MySQL/MariaDB JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_CONTAINS

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb, mysql-json

I have a table with the following structure:

```
select * from test_table;

id |load_balancer_name |listener_descriptions                                                                                                                                                                                       |
---|-------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1  |with_cert_1        |[{"Listener": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "LoadBalancerPort": 443, "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP", "InstancePort": 9005, "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"}, "PolicyNames": ["xxxx"]}] |
2  |with_cert_1        |[{"Listener": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "LoadBalancerPort": 443, "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP", "InstancePort": 9005, "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"}, "PolicyNames": ["xxxx"]}] |
3  |with_cert_2        |[{"Listener": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "LoadBalancerPort": 443, "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP", "InstancePort": 9005, "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/yyy"}, "PolicyNames": ["xxxx"]}] |
4  |no_cert            |                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
```

What I need is to do some searcches based on the `listener_descriptions` column. To ensure `JSON_*` method works, I 
did this query, that works fine:

```
select 
id, load_balancer_name,
JSON_EXTRACT(listener_descriptions, "$[*].Listener.SSLCertificateId")
from test_table;

id |load_balancer_name |JSON_EXTRACT(listener_descriptions, "$[*].Listener.SSLCertificateId") |
---|-------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
1  |with_cert_1        |["arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"]                        |
2  |with_cert_1        |["arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"]                        |
3  |with_cert_2        |["arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/yyy"]                        |
4  |no_cert            |                                                                      |
```

Now I want to select all rows with matching `SSLCertificateId`:

```
select 
*
from test_table
where JSON_CONTAINS(listener_descriptions, '"arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"', "$[*].Listener.SSLCertificateId")
;
```

But no results found. I have tried with multiple combinations of single and double quotes in the second parameter of `JSON_CONTAINS` without success.

```
version()                                |
-----------------------------------------|
10.3.8-MariaDB-1:10.3.8+maria~bionic-log |
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use JSON to store this data? The JSON data has the same set of attributes on every row. You could have just created real columns for each of the attributes. Then you could search with `WHERE SSLCertificateId = '...'`

Comment: @BillKarwin `listener_descriptions` is a list, it can contain multiple objects, so `SSLCertificateId` can be multiple. There are a lot of approaches, most of them better, but...

Comment: That sounds like a simple one-to-many relationship. You should have a `load_balancer` table and a `listener` table with one listener per row, each referencing its `load_balancer`. If you have multiple policies per listener, then a third table `listener_policy` with one policy per row, each referencing its listener.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JSON_CONTAINS()` doesn't allow `[*]` in its path. Instead, use `JSON_EXTRACT()` to extract the array of all certs, and use `JSON_CONTAINS()` on that.

```
select *
FROM test_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(listener_descriptions, "$[*].Listener.SSLCertificateId"), '"arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxx"')
;
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/OWLB3201)